# Javascript: How to access object member from event callback function

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, object

I have some problems trying to figure out what is wrong with my object design.

```
var comment = function(){
var textarea = null;
$(document).ready( init );

function init()
{
    $('.reply').click( comment.reply_to );
    this.textarea = $('.commentbox textarea');
    console.log( this.textarea );   // properly shows the textarea element
    console.log( textarea );        // outputs null
}

function set_text( the_text )
{
    console.log( textarea );        // outputs null
    console.log( this.textarea );   // outputs undefined
    textarea.val( the_text );
}

return {
    reply_to: function()
    {
        console.log( this );            // outputs the element who fired the event
        set_text( 'a test text' );      // properly gets called.
    }
};
}();
```

When document is fully loaded, init() is automatically called and initializes the object. I must note that the textarea member properly points to the desired element.
A click event is attached to a "reply" button, so reply_to() function is called whenever user clicks on it.

So, this is what I don't understand:
* When using "this" is safe? Using it from reply_to() it is not, as it seems like the context is set to the caller element.
* Why I can call "set_text()" from reply_to, but I cannot access the "textarea" member?
* How I should do to access "textarea" member from reply_to() (which is an event callback)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since inside those handlers the context will change, it's easiest to keep a reference to the context you want, I personally prefer `self`.  Here's one alternative format:

```
var comment = function(){
    this.textarea = null;
    var self = this;
    $(document).ready( init );

    function init()
    {
        $('.reply').click( reply_to );
        self.textarea = $('.commentbox textarea');
    }

    function set_text( the_text )
    {
        self.textarea.val( the_text );
    }

    function reply_to() {
      set_text( 'a test text' );
    }
}();
```

[You can test it here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/etuMZ/). Admittedly though I'm not *really* sure what you're trying to accomplish though.  You are trying to return the `reply_to` function, but bind it yourself inside the `init()` ready handler...so you can either bind it immediately (like above), or change it up and return what you want to bind elsewhere.

Comment: I return it because I want it to be public. Although I didn't test if for use it as a callback it needs to be public... I will test it

Comment: Ok, it doesn't need to be public.