# 'this' is unequal to Bar in prototype

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, callback

In the following code snippet, 'this.x()' can only be called in case 2 (see *main()*).
Also Bar unequals this in case 1, but is equal for case 2.

```
function Class_Bar() {
    this.panel = null;
    this.init = function () {
        // do some stuff
        this.panel = 20;
    }
    this.apply = function () {
        alert(Bar == this);
        Bar.x();
        this.x();
    }
    this.x = function() {
        alert("Some friendly message");
        alert(Bar.panel);
    }
}

var Bar = new Class_Bar();

function Class_Factory() {
    this.factories = new Array();
    this.add = function (init, apply) {
        this.factories.push({"init":init, "apply":apply});
    }
    this.init = function () {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.factories.length; ++i) {
            this.factories[i]["init"]();
        }
    }
    this.apply = function () {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.factories.length; ++i) {
            this.factories[i]["apply"]();
        }
    }
}

var Factory = new Class_Factory();

function main() {
    // Case 1
    Factory.add(Bar.init, Bar.apply);

    Factory.init();
    Factory.apply();

    // Case 2
    Bar.init();
    Bar.apply();
}

main();
```

http://pastebin.com/fpjPNphx

Any ideas how to "fix" / workaround this behaviour?

I found a possible solution, but it seems to be a "bad" hack.: [Javascript: How to access object member from event callback function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4344287/javascript-how-to-access-object-member-from-event-callback-function)

Comment: I would consider passing the objects themselves to the factory if I were you, would make more sense in the context of what you are trying to do imho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By passing `Bar.init`, you're really only passing the function but not the information that it belongs to `Bar` (i.e. what the `this` value should be). What you can do is binding that information:

```
Factory.add(Bar.init.bind(Bar), Bar.apply.bind(Bar));
```